# Flutter: Is there a VSCode "when clause" for the widget inspector?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'd like `shift+cmd+i` to toggle `Inspect Widget` (in other words, when inspecting a widget in the DevTools Widget Inspector page, the shortcut should run `Cancel Widget Inspection`).

I need a "when clause" for my keyboard bindings to detect this, like

```
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+i",
        "command": "flutter.inspectWidget"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+i",
        "command": "flutter.cancelInspectWidget"
        "when": "INSPECTING_A_WIDGET" // what to put here?
    }
```

Does it exist?  Or more generally, is there code I can search to find all of Flutter's when clauses?

**Update:**

Following the accepted answer's instructions, the DevTools console showed that `dart-code:flutter.isInspectingWidget` was enabled.  The following keyboard shortcuts now toggle widget inspection:

```
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+i",
        "command": "flutter.inspectWidget"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+i",
        "command": "flutter.cancelInspectWidget",
        "when": "dart-code:flutter.isInspectingWidget"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Put the focus in the element
- Execute: **Help** | **Toggle Developer Tools**
- Execute command: **Developer: Inspect Context Keys**
- inspect the console (press Escape to open it) and see if there is a context key that is true when the element has focus.  In your case, `dart-code:flutter.isInspectingWidget` should be `true`.

Comment: @MichaelGundlach putting the focus after listing the context keys shows the keys for the previous focus location

Comment: Oh thanks, I could have sworn I had to poke it in the other order to see what I needed. I'll fix my edit :)